# Adding Global passwords to Jenkins using groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gitlab

Im provisioning my Jenkins using groovy, I need to configure Jenkins.
To be specific Manage Jenkins - configure system
Like Global password, Gitlab configuration and  Project configuration.
I'm new to groovy I have very less knowledge on groovy.
It would be really helpful if anyone can share groovy script to configure Jenkins?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a great idea , I just did the same when we upgrade to Jenkins 2.

here are some links :
https://pghalliday.com/jenkins/groovy/sonar/chef/configuration/management/2014/09/21/some-useful-jenkins-groovy-scripts.html

https://github.com/DotCi/jenkinsci-dotci-example/blob/master/configure-dotci.groovy

https://gist.github.com/vrivellino/97954495938e38421ba4504049fd44ea

BTW , you can install your plugins using CLI it will save you time in the future.

if you have specific question , let me know

Thanks , Mor

Comment: Thanks Mor, These scripts helped a lot